# Error posting a REST request via cross domain library - Cannot handle Taxonomy Field Value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have an app that updates a list item then starts a workflow on it.  It was working fine, then stopped working the other day. It has started throwing an error regarding Taxonomy fields, but I am not changing any taxonomy fields. Here is the code:

```
var d = $.Deferred(),
    oDataUrl = this.appUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists(guid'c7c44153-67ad-4189-be89-91b6603ea774')/Items(462)?@target='" + encodeURIComponent(this.hostUrl) + "'",
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(this.appUrl);
var executeOptions = {
    url: oDataUrl,
    method: type,
    headers: {
        "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
        "If-Match":"*"
    },
    success: xDomainRequestSuccess,
    error: xDomainRequestFail
};
if (dataBody) {
    executeOptions.body = JSON.stringify(dataBody);
}
    
executor.executeAsync(executeOptions);

function xDomainRequestSuccess(data) {
    d.resolve((data.body) ? JSON.parse(data.body) : data);
}

function xDomainRequestFail(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        console.log(Object.keys(data)[i] + ': ' + data[Object.keys(data)[i]]);
    }
    d.reject('Failed to perform the request.  Error: ' + errorMessage);
}

return d.promise();
```

Here is the error message:

> "code":"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException"
>
> "value":"Cannot handle the type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue'."

The Stage field is a choice field, and the emailComments a multi line of text field.  The list does contain some managed metadata fields, but none are being updated by the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to an issue posted here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e0579c4f-6bb6-4961-85bb-b82b4c26e496/workflow-does-not-run-properly-httpinternalservererror?forum=sharepointcustomization

I'm using SharePoint Designer workflows within Office 365, and the workflows suddenly stopped working Monday afternoon, with exactly the same error as you are seeing.

Our workaround was to rebuild the workflow using the 2010 workflow engine, we also have a support call open with Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, our workflows have stopped working as well.  My workaround for updating the item with the app was to use JSOM, but then we discovered the workflows.  We also have a support call with Microsoft.  We're telling them the issue is not Workflow related, as it's impacting REST calls, but they won't listen.